# Javascript error in IE 8 with compatibility mode enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm testing my site in IE8 in compatibility mode and giving the following javascript error:

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;. NET CLR 2.0.50727;. NET CLR 3.0.04506.648;. NET CLR 3.5.21022;. NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152;. NET CLR 3.5.30729;. NET4.0C;. NET4.0; InfoPath.1;. NET CLR 1.1.4322; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
>   Timestamp: Tue, 17 May 2011 20:37:05 UTC

```
Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 24
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br/Project/Details?ProjectID=100
```

The page link is:
http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br/Project/Details?ProjectID=100

I could not understand exactly where the error is not even fix it

Comment: Next time, please add relevant parts of your code. In this case, you could easily have extracted the script block around line 24.

Comment: I have several scripts, I do not even know which script to look like 24 could draw the line?

Comment: Look at my answer. Look at the source in your file at the provided link. Do you see where line 24 is? There's a clear code block there, you could have copy-pasted that in your question.

Comment: Yes, now I have seen.
Sorry, I thought the error was one of the files. js.
There was no thinking about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#menu").treeview({
    animated: "fast",
    collapsed: true,
    unique: true,
});
```

The error is due to the superfluous comma after your last item.